# Summation of matrices

Tags: matlab

I want to sum together each cell in the same position for each matrix. I have k amount of (i,j) matrices stored in MATLAB as (i,j,k) and I want to create one matrix which is the sum of all them - however the MATLAB command sums together every value in each column whereas I want to sum together each cell in the same position from each matrix.

```
 1  3  4       3  4  0        2  4  4
 0  3  1       2  7  8        0  3  1 
 9  0  2       0  1  2        1  2  3
```

I want to create a matrix that is:

```
 1+3+2   3+4+4    4+0+4
 0+2+1   3+7+3    1+8+1
 9+0+1   0+1+2    2+2+3
```

=

```
6   11  8
3   13  10
10  3   7
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a second input to [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) specifying the dimension along which to sum (in your case, 3):

```
>> A(:,:,1) = [ 1  3  4      
                0  3  1       
                9  0  2 ];
>> A(:,:,2) = [ 3  4  0        
                2  7  8        
                0  1  2 ];   
>> A(:,:,3) = [ 2  4  4
                0  3  1 
                1  2  3 ];

>> sum(A,3)
ans =
     6    11     8
     2    13    10
    10     3     7
```

Comment: Please see edit as when I tried the code I didn't get the same answer as you.

Comment: @user3190506 It's `sum(A,3)`, not `sum(A,2)`.  You want to sum along the _third_ dimension

Comment: I thought you used the 3 because there were 3 matrices, not because of 3rd dimension! Apologies and thank you.